# Python - How to add convex hull to selected verts?

Tags: python, bmesh

The left convex hull is created in `object mode` and the right convex hull is created in `edit mode`

I want the convex hull of selected verts only and not the entire object in the new object

[image]

[image]

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

if bpy.context.object.mode == 'EDIT':
    verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
else:
    verts = bm.verts

hull = bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=verts, use_existing_faces=True)
bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=hull["geom_unused"] + hull["geom_interior"], context='VERTS',)


name = 'Convex Hull'
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
mesh.update()
bm.clear()

object = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(object)
```

Comment: I *think* you're supposed to use [from_edit_mesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html?highlight=from_edit_mesh#bmesh.from_edit_mesh) to access bmesh data in edit mode

Answer (score 3):

Your bmesh handling code won't work because you create bmeshes differently depending on whether you are in edit mode or any other mode.  Also, you should validate the indices before you iterate through `bm.verts`.

Here is code that will properly do what you want, assuming you want to use the active object:

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

object = bpy.context.object
if not object.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(object.data)
else:
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(object.data)

bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

if object.mode == 'EDIT':
    verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
else:
    verts = bm.verts

hull = bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=verts, use_existing_faces=True)
bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=hull["geom_unused"] + hull["geom_interior"], context='VERTS',)

if not object.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm.to_mesh(object.data)
    bm.free()
else:
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(object.data)
```

However, if you want to keep the original and do this to a duplicate, then you have to make a copy *before* the `object =`  line at the top of this code.

Comment: I want the convex hull of selected verts in the new object

Comment: Then duplicate the object before you invoke this code.  How to properly duplicate an object is a separate question.